# creating a matrix with the sum of payment depending on date1 (row) and date2 (column) in R

Tags: r

I have a database with two dates (sold date and pay date), I would like to create a N x M matrix with the sum of the values depending of the dates like that:

[image]

the database code of the example is here:

```
#creating base
sold_date <- as.Date(c("01-01-2019", "01-01-2019", "01-02-2019", "01-02-2019", "01-03-2019", "01-01-2019"), "%d-%m-%Y")
pay_date <- as.Date(c("01-01-2019", "01-01-2019", "01-03-2019", "01-02-2019", "01-03-2019", "01-02-2019"), "%d-%m-%Y")
value <- c(10, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20)
base <- data.frame(sold_date, pay_date, value)
```

how can I do this?

best regards

Comment: Your code doesn't match the example above...

Comment: @AntoniosK thanks for the warning, I have corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

base %>%
  group_by(sold_date, pay_date) %>%  # get unique pairs of dates
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%  # and get sum of values
  ungroup() %>%                      # forget the grouping
  spread(pay_date, value, fill = 0)  # reshape dataset

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   sold_date  `2019-01-01` `2019-02-01` `2019-03-01` `2019-04-01`
#   <date>            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 2019-01-01           10           20            0            0
# 2 2019-02-01            0            0            5           10
# 3 2019-03-01            0            0           15            0
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` approach where pivoting and aggregating can be done in a single step:

```
data.table::dcast(
  setDT(base), sold_date ~ pay_date, 
  value.var = 'value', 
  fun.aggregate = sum
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

base %>%
  group_by(sold_date, pay_date) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = pay_date, values_from = value, values_fill = list(value = 0))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   sold_date [3]
  sold_date  `2019-01-01` `2019-02-01` `2019-03-01` `2019-04-01`
  <date>            <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 2019-01-01           10           20            0            0
2 2019-02-01            0            0            5           10
3 2019-03-01            0            0           15            0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example data does not have multiple entries with same sold_date - pay_date combinations, i fixed that for you:

```
sold_date <- as.Date(c("01-01-2019", "01-01-2019", "01-02-2019", "01-03-2019", "01-01-2019"), "%d-%m-%Y")
pay_date <- as.Date(c("01-03-2019", "01-03-2019", "01-04-2019", "01-03-2019", "01-02-2019"), "%d-%m-%Y")
value <- c(10, 5, 10, 15, 20)
base <- data.frame(sold_date, pay_date, value)
```

Then we can use `dplyr` syntax to group 'sold_date' and 'pay_date' and sum the value of thevariable 'value' for each group:

```
base %>% 
  group_by(sold_date, pay_date) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(value))
```

If you want the data in the form as shown in your original question we can use dplyr::pivot_wider:

```
base %>% 
  group_by(sold_date, pay_date) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = pay_date,
              values_from = Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `reshape` + `aggregate`

```
dfout <- reshape(aggregate(value ~ sold_date + pay_date,df,sum), 
                 direction = "wide",
                 idvar = "sold_date",
                 timevar = "pay_date")
```

such that

```
> dfout
   sold_date value.2019-01-01 value.2019-02-01 value.2019-03-01
1 2019-01-01               13               20               NA
3 2019-02-01               NA               10                5
5 2019-03-01               NA               NA               15
```

If you want to fill `NA` with `0`, then you append `dfout[is.na(dfout)] <- 0` to the end of codes from above, such that

```
> dfout
   sold_date value.2019-01-01 value.2019-02-01 value.2019-03-01
1 2019-01-01               13               20                0
3 2019-02-01                0               10                5
5 2019-03-01                0                0               15
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(sold_date = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17928, 17928, 
17956, 17897), class = "Date"), pay_date = structure(c(17897, 
17897, 17956, 17928, 17956, 17928), class = "Date"), value = c(10, 
3, 5, 10, 15, 20)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```